# Android action bar not placing buttons linearly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I have an activity where I am showing ActionBar. I have split mode enabled and on bottom bar i am showing 4 menu items. The icons are all sized 32 dp. However all the icons are not horizontally aligned.

The first two buttons are closer to each other. The third button takes half of action bar space and 4th button is relatively on right.

On pressed 3rd Button shows the space taken is much more.

What is this behavior and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are the actual .png or whatever the same size? (not sure if it matters, but just trying to think of what it might be ;))

Comment: Please post the xml file so that we can identify where could be the possible cause.

Comment: Please post the action bar layout XML.

Comment: This is not layout xml, these are menu items   <item
      android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
      android:icon="@drawable/menu_btn"
      android:showAsAction="always">

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure all the images are of **same size**.
2. If you are using custom view to inflate into actionbar, use `LinearLayout` and set LinearLayout's `layoutWeightSum="4"` and give `layout_weight="1"` to all it's child.

**Edit** : as per your comment, in top `custom_layout.xml` use the below layout. Also note  **android:layout_width="0dp"** in the parentlayout

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Bottom bar is not customView , top bar is always custom view

Comment: are those actionBar's "Images/Layout" are in a seperate xml?

Comment: The top bar is a custom view named custom_layout.xml where as the Bottom bar is Meny items in menu folder menu.xml. It contain <item></items> 4 Of them

Comment: I am NOT using any layouts. The bottm bar is Showing "Menu" items <item></item> it is not a custom view. It is a menu

Comment: This seems to be the solution as per your question, probably you should consider updating your question, am the not the only one to post similar solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided the images are all the same width, you have two options:

1. Use `weightSum` and `layout_weight` to set the icons to take up equal amounts of spacing.
2. Manually set the padding, like so:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
     <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
     <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
   </style>
   <style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
     <item name="android:minWidth">32dip</item>
     <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
   </style>
   ```